# does the area converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fractals

[image: tree]

If all shaded blocks are squares derived from the largest one with edge length 1, does the area converge?

Comment: Can you write a series based on the combined areas of each size of square?

Comment: @Henry I can’t as the squares overlap...

Comment: I don't think the overlap matters to write down a series as Henry suggested.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier if there’s no overlap , the area will be 1+2*1/2 + 4*1/4 ... not converging .but with overlap , I don’t know..

Comment: I see! You don't want to count several times the area when there is an overlap. Nice question.

Comment: Do you know if the diameter of the whole picture tends to infinity? If it doesn't that would solve the problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal) there's a section area.

Comment: OP asks for *convergence* of the area instead of the *value* of this convergence, so I think we can bound it by counting the overlapped regions multiple times, so that we have a monotonically increasing sequence bouned by another one.

Comment: @GNUSupporter yes, the link provided says that little is known about the actual value of the area. All that is known is that it is $<18$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier you are right, it converges

Comment: @JohnDoe I have to correct myself.  Wiki says it's bouned by a $6 \times 4$ rectangle, so it converges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The horizontal distance from the midpoint of the largest square to the leftmost point can be computed as $$\frac12+\frac12+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^4+\cdots\\=1+2\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)=3$$
So the total width of the system is $6$. The total height is $$1+1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^4+\cdots=4$$
So, as the wiki article says, it is bounded in a $6\times 4$ box, and so is finite in area.